# Typo in "composer config" command broke composer

Tags: composer-php

I am very new to Composer. I followed instructions to install a new module (Drupal 8), and I had a typo in the command. I typed: `composer config repositories.drupal composer https:packages.drupal.org/8` when it was supposed to be `composer config repositories.drupal composer https://packages.drupal.org/8`

Now no matter what composer command I give, it responds with: [UnexpectedValueException]
Invalid url given for Composer repository: http://https:packages.drupal.org/8

I've tried numerous troubleshooting composer commands, and everything returns the same. Is this saved in a config file somewhere? How has no one mistyped this command anywhere such that Google can't find any answers to this? It seems like it would be a common mistake.

Thanks in advance for your help! I'll also apologize in advance for my first question on the site. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I'd be glad to clarify anything! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I looked in the /vendor/composer folder to find composer.json, but the error wasn't there. I ended up doing a search for recently updated files, and found composer.json in the root folder that was changed recently.

Digging in, I found the error in an array. I edited the array through a text editor and now all is well. I'd still like to know if there is a command that I could have done to repair the typo. It seems like a strange thing to cause it to completely stop working.

Hopefully, this will help someone else who had the same problem. Look for multiple versions of composer.json!

Comment: You should share the location of the `composer.json` you are using. Usually, the error should be in the root version of that file for your project